Parameter in click() fireEvent
In Jest, I am using fireEvent.click(). I want to pass the parameter of the function that will be called after I click that button for click event.
expect(Searchmodal).toBeDefined();
render(<Searchmodal visible={true} />);
const button = screen.getByTestId("test-button");
const parameter = "123";

act(() => {
  fireEvent.click(button, { target: { value: parameter } });
});

const { getByPlaceholderText } = render(<Searchmodal />);
const input = getByPlaceholderText("Search");
expect(input.value).toBe(parameter);

This code is failing to pass the parameter. How to pass the parameter in this fireEvent? This is the JSX file component:
<button
  id="datasource-link-apply-button"
  data-testid="test-button"
  type="secondary"
  onClick={() => handleApplyClick("890")}
>
  Apply
</button>

I tried:
{
      target: {
        value: parameter;
      }
    }

but it's not working.

You mean the value passed to handleApplyClick? That's always "890", as set in the component itself. (Also you should really be using the role-based, selectors, in this case getByRole("button", { name: /Apply/ })).

no the value can be anything

Not if you're talking about clicking on the Apply button, it can't. It's hard-coded in the component, the actual event is ignored completely. Please give a [mre] and explain what you're actually trying to test here, your question makes no sense.

yes the parameter can be anything
My question is
in fireEvent I want to click component and pass a parameter from the fireEvent only

Again, not in onClick={() => handleApplyClick("890")} it can't. The event isn't even defined as a parameter to that callback, it's ignored entirely. You're not going to be able to write a test for code you fundamentally do not understand.

okay, please tell me how to test a function by passing a parameter in jest in functional component in react.

It's still unclear what parameter you're even talking about. The parameters to a function component are the props, which you're already passing: <Searchmodal visible={true} />. But the click that you're trying to simulate, for the final time, does not use the event. onClick={() => handleApplyClick("890")} means handleApplyClick (whatever that is, it's not a prop and you didn't bother to give a [mre]) is always called with "890" and the event is ignored entirely. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

I want to test function handleApplyClick(value) ,
const handleApplyClickss = (val) => {
setText(val);
};

Great, so simulate the click (you're already doing that) and assert that the correct value ("890") is getting set as a result. It's not at all clear why you think that's parameterised, assuming you can see the same code you're posting here.
